# Assign Class method functionality in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to assign a Class method functionality in the Class constructor?

For example, I have the `Button` class:

```
class Button {
  constructor(
    public label: string,
    public icon: string,
    public action: () => void
  ) { }
}
```

Now I would like to assign `action()`'s functionality like:

```
const b = new Button('My button', 'info', () => 2 + 3);
```

If I do that, `action()` is created empty.

**UPDATE:** The above code works.

Comment: `action` is empty after the constructor gets executed ? It works for me, after the button constructor is executed the action field has the function in it

Comment: Really? I get the label and the icon fine, but action is an empty function: `function() {}`

Comment: I took the compiled code and executed it in the chrome console .. check if the assignment exists in the generated js, maybe it did not compile

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try it. Thank you

Comment: My code works. It turns out I was calling the `action()` methord wrong. The debugger was showing the function empty, but apparently that is how it shows it. Now I'm calling it right and the functionality is correctly assigned. Thanks